# "Tricking" EF core to use unique key instead of primary key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first-mapping

I have a database at work that has tables without primary keys (Sql Server). It uses a different schema. It has a unique (sometimes compound) key for each table. I cannot modify database in any way. It is a vendor's database.

Is it ok to trick EF into thinking the unique key is the primary key? Will there be any issues with inserting or updating records?

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: I mean, instead of declaring this an Index can I declare this as the primary key? This must have been the database developers intention for these tables.

Comment: are you saying that neither the possibility of defining composed PKs (https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/keys.html) or alternate keys (https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/alternate-keys.html) will help and you are looking for a different solution? Also just a quick catch-up for you, EF7 was renamed to EF Core :)

Comment: I cannot modify the database. They have a convention for their unique index as a fake primary key.

Comment: Also cannot use alternate key because alt keys are in conjunction with a primary key

Comment: @JulieLerman I do want to use the fluent key was wondering if there is issues using it that way with a unique index instead of an actual key

Comment: Did you try scaffolding the dbcontext (reverse engineer) ?

Comment: @ErikEJ yes does not scaffold those tables